# Best way to store small, alternating, public data that updates every couple of hours?

Tags: java, sql, database

The essence of my problem is that there are too many solutions, and I would like to find which one wins out in pros and cons before I build an infrastructure around it.

(Simplified for the purpose of this forum) This is an auction site where five auctions are stored in a rank #1-5, #1 being the currently featured auction. The other four are simply "on deck." After either a couple hours or the completion of that auction, #2-5 move up to #1-4 and a new one is chosen to be #5

I'm using a dedicated server and I've been considering just storing the data in the servlet or maybe adding a column in the database as a boolean for each auction...like "isFeatured = 1"

Suffice it to say the data is read about 5 times+ more often than it is written, which is why I'm leaning towards good old SQL.

Comment: Shouldn't you just remove the first one, and insert a new one? For retrieval, just order the records based on Creation date ascending. By doing this you don't need update the rank column on the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can retrieve the relevant auctions from DB with a simple query with `ORDER BY` and `TOP` or something similar then try this. If no performance issues occur then [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and you're done.

Otherwise when these 5 auctions are valid for a while then cache them in memory. Have a singleton holding these auctions and provide methods for updating for example. Maybe you want to use a caching lib instead. Update these Top5 whenever necessary but serve them directly out of memory without hiting a DB or something similar expensive.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of scale are you looking for? How many application servers need access to the data?

I think you're probably making this more complicated than it is. Just use a database, take a hit of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), and move onto whatever else you need to work on. :P

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Suffice it to say, I'm a front end developer being asked to do backend work. Don't know what an app server is or how many will be accessing it, but it's supposed to be built to be very scalable. Anyway, yes, maybe I'm just making this more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/)?  It allows for "good old SQL" without all of the hassles of setting up a separate database server.  As long as the data isn't too huge (to be fair, I haven't tested the size limits, but I've skimmed blog entries mentioning the use of SQLite to process files of several dozen MB in size quickly and with no problems), you should be fine.

It isn't a perfect solution for all needs (frankly, I sometimes find the [dynamic typing](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) to be a pain), but since it relies on locally stored files, reads will be much faster than firing up a network connection to talk to a more "traditional" RDBMS.

Comment: Yeah, the data isn't terribly big. I think I'll use plain MySQL since that's what's already being used here. Thanks.